# WPF Built-In Dynamic Resources

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I'm trying to modify a copy of the style template for ContextMenu.
There is the following line -

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuPopupBackgroundBrush}"/>
```

How do I find the definition for the DynamicResource MenuPopupBackgroundBrush?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it will show you using together **Live Visual Tree** and **Live Property Explorer**, but it is not very consistent. A more sure fire way of finding out is by simply naming the component using the particular resource you're interested in and looking it up in a **Watch** window. For instance:

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuPopupBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource MenuPopupBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.DropShadowKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MessageFontFamilyKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MessageFontSizeKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemFonts.MessageFontWeightKey}}"/>
</Style>

<Button>
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Name="cm1" Style="{DynamicResource ContextMenuStyle1}" >
            <MenuItem Header="Item 1"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

[image]

So, you can verify that `MenuPopupBackgroundBrush` is a `SolidColorBrush` with color `#FFF5F5F5`.